# SNMP network bandwith logger-monitor

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp

I have a switch working with SNMP protocol. I want to get/log or monitor the data of bandwith for switch and connected devices/ports. the amount of incoming or outgoing data have to be calculated periodically into a log file simply.

As another option, a simple program for monitoring the network bandwith, total data traffic etc. of SNMP network may be useful for me. But it have to be so compact and light software. many programs are not freeware and their sizes are very big. Is there a solution to do that process? Thanks..

Comment: Look at [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) for bandwidth monitoring, use [collectd](http://collectd.org/) as the SNMP poller

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces monitored through SNMP report their data usage in the ifInOctets and ifOutOctets counters.  The numbers they report can't be used directly; you need to sample them every X minutes or seconds, where X gets smaller the faster the interface.  You simply subtract the previous number from the current one to give you how much traffic went by during those X minutes.  Watch out for wrapping as it gets to the 32 bit integer limit (it certainly won't send negative traffic ;-)  The number X will be greatly affected by how long it takes to wrap a 32 bit number at the interfaces maximum speed.

If you have a high speed switch, ideally you should actually use the ifHCInOctets and ifHCOutOctets if your switch supports it.  These are 64-bit numbers and won't wrap frequently and thus X can become much much larger.  But not all devices support them.